# delete the first 2 words in a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to both Perl and reg-ex's, and I'm trying to remove the first two word in a string

Please how can I delete the first 2 words in a string using regular expression. 
For example
The Input String is `One two three four`
Output should be `three four`

I tried `^(?:\w+\s+){2}([^\n\r]+)$`  and it works fine on regex online testing tool but when I run it in my application the output is the same as the input string

Pls. Advise

Comment: Show your code.  You need to perform some sort of _substitution_ too.  Simply matching the pattern wouldn't delete the words.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the Substitution Operator ([`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace))

```
my $str = "One two three four";
$str =~ s/^(?:\w+\s+){2}//;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried the below and still I could not find the right syntax                                                           Input String:  one two three four
^(?:\w+\s+){2}       >>>>>>>>>>> output: one two
s/^(?:\w+\s+){2}//        >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null ( which is Expected)
~s/^\S+\s+\S+\s+//;    >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null
~s/^(?:\w+\s+){2}//;   >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
$str=~s/^\S+\s+\S+\s+//;
```

will replace first two words with an empty string thus effectively deleting it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried the below and still I could not find the right syntax                                                           Input String:  one two three four
^(?:\w+\s+){2}       >>>>>>>>>>> output: one two
s/^(?:\w+\s+){2}//        >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null ( which is Expected)
~s/^\S+\s+\S+\s+//;    >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null
~s/^(?:\w+\s+){2}//;   >>>>>>>>>>> output: Null

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "One two three four";
my ($match) = $str =~ /^(?:\w+\s+){2}([^\n\r]+)$/;
print "$match\n";
```

---

three four